# Export Apexcharts to XLS file

Tags: javascript, webforms, apexcharts

Does anyone know how to get data value from apexcharts into xls file?
i've search it on github and get nothing.

i already tried to add export to xls into apexchart's toolbar via apexcharts.min.js file
anyone know how to make it work in asp.net webforms?

```
key: "_createHamburgerMenu",
  value: function _createHamburgerMenu(parent) {
    this.elMenuItems = [];
    parent.appendChild(this.elMenu);
    Graphics.setAttrs(this.elMenu, {
      class: 'apexcharts-menu'
    });
    var menuItems = [{
      name: 'exportSVG',
      title: this.localeValues.exportToSVG
    }, {
      name: 'exportPNG',
      title: this.localeValues.exportToPNG
    }, {
      name: 'exportCSV',
      title: this.localeValues.exportToCSV
    }, {
      name: 'exportXLS',
      title: this.localeValues.exportToXLS
    }];

key: "handleDownload",
  value: function handleDownload(type) {
    var w = this.w;
    var exprt = new Exports(this.ctx);

    switch (type) {
      case 'svg':
        exprt.exportToSVG(this.ctx);
        break;

      case 'png':
        exprt.exportToPng(this.ctx);
        break;

      case 'csv':
        exprt.exportToCSV({
          series: w.config.series,
          columnDelimiter: w.config.chart.toolbar.export.csv.columnDelimiter
        });
        break;

        case 'xls':
            exprt.exportToXLS(this.ctx);   //alert('Export');
            break;
    }

key: "exportToXLS",
  value: function exportToXLS() {
      var w = this.w;
      if (w.config.ident === undefined)
          alert(w.globals.chartID);
      else //alert(w.config.ident);
      w.config.chart.toolbar.export.xls.fmtClick(w.config.ident, w);
    //this.triggerDownload(this.svgUrl(), null, '.xls');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to gain access to an instance of the Export class. Once you have that, you can trigger the methods the chart uses to download csv, svg etc.

```
var cts = chart.ctx;
ctx.exports.exportToSVG(ctx);
ctx.exports.exportToCSV({
    series: your.chart.series,
    columnDelimiter: ','
});
```

For more details see the source code here: https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/blob/master/src/modules/Toolbar.js

You will need to run this client side script using your preferred method of choice in webforms.

Answer (score 0):

```
chart.exports.exportToCSV({
      series: chart.series.t,
      columnDelimiter: ',',
    })
```

this will work i tried and success